# Problemas com sweetalert2 e bootstrap4

Tags: bootstrap-4, sweetalert2

Montei uma página onde o cliente precisa digitar seu cpf para prosseguir.
Inclui mensagens de erro com sweetalert2 so que ao exibi-las não é possível fechar.
O box do sweet-alert não é clicável e quando tento clicar em qualquer coisa, ele clica no objeto atrás dele.

segue meu código https://pastebin.com/RL696SQE

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 
        <title>Ponto de Cadastramento</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
       
        <link href="https://painel.aivisual.com.br/assets/css/paper-dashboard23cd.css?v=1.2.2" rel="stylesheet"/>
 
        <link href="https://painel.aivisual.com.br/assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
        <style CSS>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
            }
            body{
                background:#7da6af;
            }
            .swal2-container {
              z-index: 10000;
            }     
        </style>       
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='container h-100'>
            <div class="row h-100 justify-content-md-center">
               
                <div class="col-md-6 my-auto card">
                    <div class='card-content'>
                        <div class='row justify-content-md-center'>
                            <div class='col-md-6'><img src='https://painel.aivisual.com.br/img/logo.svg' class='img-fluid'></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='row justify-content-md-center'>
                            <div class='col-md-12'>
                                <center>&nbsp;<br><h5>Seja bem vindo!</h5><p>Para iniciar o cadastro, digite o seu CPF ou RA no campo abaixo</p></center>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='row justify-content-md-center'>
                            <div class='col-md-12'>
                                <input class="form-control form-control-lg numerocad" type="text" placeholder="CPF / RA" id="registro">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='row justify-content-md-center'>
                            <div class='col-md-12'>&nbsp;<br>
                                <button type="button" class="form-control form-control-lg btn btn-primary btn-lg btnnext active">Prosseguir</button>                           
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='row justify-content-md-center'>
                            <div class='col-md-12'>&nbsp;<br>
                                <center><b>Powered by: <a href='https://aiknow.ai' target='aiknow' style='color:#0062cc'>Aiknow</a></b></center>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>     
    </body>
 
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
 
  <script src="https://painel.aivisual.com.br/assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
  <script src="https://painel.aivisual.com.br/assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://painel.aivisual.com.br/assets/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>    
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@latest"></script>
 
 
    <script>
        function valCpf(cpf){
                cpf = cpf.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').toString();
 
                if( cpf.length == 11 )
                {
                    var v = [];
 
                    //Calcula o primeiro dígito de verificação.
                    v[0] = 1 * cpf[0] + 2 * cpf[1] + 3 * cpf[2];
                    v[0] += 4 * cpf[3] + 5 * cpf[4] + 6 * cpf[5];
                    v[0] += 7 * cpf[6] + 8 * cpf[7] + 9 * cpf[8];
                    v[0] = v[0] % 11;
                    v[0] = v[0] % 10;
 
                    //Calcula o segundo dígito de verificação.
                    v[1] = 1 * cpf[1] + 2 * cpf[2] + 3 * cpf[3];
                    v[1] += 4 * cpf[4] + 5 * cpf[5] + 6 * cpf[6];
                    v[1] += 7 * cpf[7] + 8 * cpf[8] + 9 * v[0];
                    v[1] = v[1] % 11;
                    v[1] = v[1] % 10;
 
                    //Retorna Verdadeiro se os dígitos de verificação são os esperados.
                    if ( (v[0] != cpf[9]) || (v[1] != cpf[10]) )
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
        }
        $(".btnnext").click(function(){
            if($("#registro").val()==""){
                Swal.fire({
                  title: 'Alerta!',
                  text: 'Para prosseguir você deve digitar seu CPF ou RA.',
                  type: 'error',
                  confirmButtonText: 'Entendi !',
                  heightAuto: false,
                })
            } else {
                if($("#registro").val().length==14){
                    if(!valCpf($("#registro").val())){
                        Swal.fire({
                          title: 'Alerta!',
                          text: 'Por favor digite um cpf válido!',
                          type: 'error',
                          confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
                            heightAuto: false
                        })                     
                    } else {
                        $.post( "https://painel.aivisual.com.br/cadastro", { numeroRegistro: $("#registro").val() }).done(function( data ) {
                            if(data=="ok"){
                                window.location.href = "https://painel.aivisual.com.br/cadastro";
                            } else {
                                Swal.fire({
                                  title: 'Alerta!',
                                  text: data,
                                  type: 'error',
                                  confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
                                    heightAuto: false
                                })
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    $.post( "https://painel.aivisual.com.br/cadastro", { numeroRegistro: $("#registro").val() }).done(function( data ) {
                        if(data=="ok"){
                            window.location.href = "https://painel.aivisual.com.br/cadastro";
                        } else {
                            Swal.fire({
                              title: 'Alerta!',
                              text: data,
                              type: 'error',
                              confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
                                    heightAuto: false
                            })
                        }
                    });
                }
               
            }
        });
 
        $(document).keypress(function(e) {
          if(e.which == 13) {
            $(".btnnext").click();
          }
        });
    </script>
 
 
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.numerocad').mask('0#', {onKeyPress: function(cep, e, field, options){
                var masks = ['0#', '000.000.000-00'];
                  mask = (cep.length>9) ? masks[1] : masks[0];
                $('.numerocad').mask(mask, options);
            }});
        });
 
        setInterval(function(){ $.post( "https://painel.aivisual.com.br/".rand(0,9999) ); }, 30000);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://painel.aivisual.com.br/assets/js/jquery.idle.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).idle({
          onIdle: function(){
            window.location.href = "https://painel.aivisual.com.br/cadastro/cancel-process";
          },
          idle: 60000
        })
 
    </script>
 
</html>
```

Comment: Cara achei uma solução, editei a resposta completamente, testa ai e me fala qq coisa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu `Alert` por algum motivo está perdendo o `pointer-event`, basicamente com esse CSS eu resolvi o problema

```
.swal2-container.swal2-center.swal2-fade.swal2-shown {
  pointer-events: initial !important;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pode testar com o código abaixo. Não mexi em nada apenas acrescentei o CSS acima

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 
        <title>Ponto de Cadastramento</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
       
        <link href="https://painel.aivisual.com.br/assets/css/paper-dashboard23cd.css?v=1.2.2" rel="stylesheet"/>
 
        <link href="https://painel.aivisual.com.br/assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
        <style CSS>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
            }
            body{
                background:#7da6af;
            }
.swal2-container.swal2-center.swal2-fade.swal2-shown {
  pointer-events: initial !important;
}  
        </style>       
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='container h-100'>
            <div class="row h-100 justify-content-md-center">
               
                <div class="col-md-6 my-auto card">
                    <div class='card-content'>
                        <div class='row justify-content-md-center'>
                            <div class='col-md-6'><img src='https://painel.aivisual.com.br/img/logo.svg' class='img-fluid'></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='row justify-content-md-center'>
                            <div class='col-md-12'>
                                <center>&nbsp;<br><h5>Seja bem vindo!</h5><p>Para iniciar o cadastro, digite o seu CPF ou RA no campo abaixo</p></center>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='row justify-content-md-center'>
                            <div class='col-md-12'>
                                <input class="form-control form-control-lg numerocad" type="text" placeholder="CPF / RA" id="registro">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='row justify-content-md-center'>
                            <div class='col-md-12'>&nbsp;<br>
                                <button type="button" class="form-control form-control-lg btn btn-primary btn-lg btnnext active">Prosseguir</button>                           
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='row justify-content-md-center'>
                            <div class='col-md-12'>&nbsp;<br>
                                <center><b>Powered by: <a href='https://aiknow.ai' target='aiknow' style='color:#0062cc'>Aiknow</a></b></center>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>     
    </body>
 
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
 
  <script src="https://painel.aivisual.com.br/assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
  <script src="https://painel.aivisual.com.br/assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://painel.aivisual.com.br/assets/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>    
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@latest"></script>
 
 
    <script>
        function valCpf(cpf){
                cpf = cpf.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').toString();
 
                if( cpf.length == 11 )
                {
                    var v = [];
 
                    //Calcula o primeiro dígito de verificação.
                    v[0] = 1 * cpf[0] + 2 * cpf[1] + 3 * cpf[2];
                    v[0] += 4 * cpf[3] + 5 * cpf[4] + 6 * cpf[5];
                    v[0] += 7 * cpf[6] + 8 * cpf[7] + 9 * cpf[8];
                    v[0] = v[0] % 11;
                    v[0] = v[0] % 10;
 
                    //Calcula o segundo dígito de verificação.
                    v[1] = 1 * cpf[1] + 2 * cpf[2] + 3 * cpf[3];
                    v[1] += 4 * cpf[4] + 5 * cpf[5] + 6 * cpf[6];
                    v[1] += 7 * cpf[7] + 8 * cpf[8] + 9 * v[0];
                    v[1] = v[1] % 11;
                    v[1] = v[1] % 10;
 
                    //Retorna Verdadeiro se os dígitos de verificação são os esperados.
                    if ( (v[0] != cpf[9]) || (v[1] != cpf[10]) )
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
        }
        $(".btnnext").click(function(){
            if($("#registro").val()==""){
                Swal.fire({
                  title: 'Alerta!',
                  text: 'Para prosseguir você deve digitar seu CPF ou RA.',
                  type: 'error',
                  confirmButtonText: 'Entendi !',
                  heightAuto: false,
                })
            } else {
                if($("#registro").val().length==14){
                    if(!valCpf($("#registro").val())){
                        Swal.fire({
                          title: 'Alerta!',
                          text: 'Por favor digite um cpf válido!',
                          type: 'error',
                          confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
                            heightAuto: false
                        })                     
                    } else {
                        $.post( "https://painel.aivisual.com.br/cadastro", { numeroRegistro: $("#registro").val() }).done(function( data ) {
                            if(data=="ok"){
                                window.location.href = "https://painel.aivisual.com.br/cadastro";
                            } else {
                                Swal.fire({
                                  title: 'Alerta!',
                                  text: data,
                                  type: 'error',
                                  confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
                                    heightAuto: false
                                })
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    $.post( "https://painel.aivisual.com.br/cadastro", { numeroRegistro: $("#registro").val() }).done(function( data ) {
                        if(data=="ok"){
                            window.location.href = "https://painel.aivisual.com.br/cadastro";
                        } else {
                            Swal.fire({
                              title: 'Alerta!',
                              text: data,
                              type: 'error',
                              confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
                                    heightAuto: false
                            })
                        }
                    });
                }
               
            }
        });
 
        $(document).keypress(function(e) {
          if(e.which == 13) {
            $(".btnnext").click();
          }
        });

        // $("html").click(function(event){
        //   $("html").removeClass("swal2-shown");
        //   $("body").removeClass("swal2-shown");
        // });
    </script>
 
 
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.numerocad').mask('0#', {onKeyPress: function(cep, e, field, options){
                var masks = ['0#', '000.000.000-00'];
                  mask = (cep.length>9) ? masks[1] : masks[0];
                $('.numerocad').mask(mask, options);
            }});
        });
 
        setInterval(function(){ $.post( "https://painel.aivisual.com.br/".rand(0,9999) ); }, 30000);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://painel.aivisual.com.br/assets/js/jquery.idle.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).idle({
          onIdle: function(){
            window.location.href = "https://painel.aivisual.com.br/cadastro/cancel-process";
          },
          idle: 60000
        })
 
    </script>
 
</html>
```

Comment: como vc fez esse videozinho? vou testar com o seu cod para ver se funciona

Comment: não funcionou aqui :(

Comment: @JasarOrion o vídeo fiz com o ScreenToGif, é free basta procurar no Google. Se não funcionou ai é pq tem alguma coisa interferindo no SweetAlert. Provavelmente se vc estiver usando dentro de um Modal vai ser algum elemento do Modal está com o Z-index maior que o do Alert ou algo do tipo. Vc vai ter que inspecionar e ver o que é que está por cima e tratar no CSS. Se vc puder posta o código no Codepen ou Jsfiddle com o erro acontecendo ajuda a te responder

Comment: da uma olhada que acontece. https://imgur.com/a/Bd1kBp6

Comment: não estou em modal.

Comment: Entendi... parece que é uma tela bem simples, pq vc não parte do modelo que eu postei ai como resposta e está funcionando direitinho e vai colocando o seu código, assim vc pode reconstruir e ver o que deu errado... Vc usou algum CSS extra ou só o do Bootstrap?

Comment: vou postar todo cod no pastebin pera ai

Comment: https://pastebin.com/RL696SQE

Comment: Acho que seu erro é com a dinamica de validação, par parece que ele entra em loop, não manjo de JS ou jQuery, e gambiarra não ajudaria nessa situação. Vou editar sua pergunta e incluir esse código

Comment: obrigado. Dei uma boa lida e pensei que estava em loop mas ele esta literalmente clicando no botão atraz do modal. tanto é que se tentar selecionar o txt que esta no popup do sweetalert ele seleciona o texto do formulário atraz.

Comment: realmente resolveu. pode me explicar como isso funciona?

Comment: @JasarOrion todo elemento por default pode ser clicado pelo mouse, mas por algum motivo o js deve ter tirado o mouse event do alerta, com esse CSS eu redefini o evento de mouse no elemento para o valor inicial, voltando a aceitar o mouse

Comment: Muito bom obrigado mesmo ^^